# Why am I receiving "Type or namespace name 'LowLevelKeyboardProc' could not be found"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am `using` the following:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
```

and I am receiving the errors here:
`private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;`

and here: `[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);`

I am using VS2012 w/C# and following this tutorial: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/

Comment: You need to create such a delegate (and associated structs) yourself.

Comment: It is a place-holder symbol in the winapi documentation, it doesn't actually exist.  You'll need to declare the delegate type yourself.  There are *many* google hits for this one.

Comment: and you can name it whatever you want, for example LLKBDProc, ... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the delegate.  The article you referenced uses:

```
private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

This is included in "Step 3" of [the referenced article](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/).

Comment: Wow... it turned out to be a typo causing the issue...

I had typed it as `LowLevelKeyBoardProc` instead of `LowLevelKeyboardProc`. It was this comment that made me notice.